# Adventure Works Site Theme for SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-2010

Does anyone know where to get the site theme for SharePoint 2010 that microsoft is using for the Adeveture Works site?  I saw it once, but cant find it now. I want to brand our site close to that.

Comment: You want to brand your site based on a widely known fictional site?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The theme you are looking for is coming from **nightandday.master** which is available in publishing site, as soon as you create a publishing site **nightandday.master** page is set as default.

Let me know in case if you need more information.

Comment: WOW, it was under my nose the whole time!

Answer (score 1):

Adventure Works is a generic name that Microsoft uses for several demo sites (much like Contoso). Adventure Works is certainly the logo that shows for the out of the box NightAndDay.master but there are other Adventure Works master page designs available from Microsoft. Currently they are only available for SharePoint 2007 but that will change in the near future. Here is one (I can only post one link because I'm new):

- http://bit.ly/oEExq

Randy Drisgill - MVP SharePoint Server | My Blog: blog.drisgill.com | My Book:
www.amazon.com/gp/product/0470584645/

Comment: Randy, great to meet you, can you shoot me an email: bill.daugherty@yesprep.org?  I want to connect with you.  I also have a blog: http://www.myspexp.com